# magento 1.9 correct way to extend Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController

Tags: php, adminhtml, extensions, catalog, controllers

y'all.  What is the best way to achieve this epic feat of intellectual prowess?

Is this a good start?

```
require_once("mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController");
class Company_adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController extends Mage_AdminhtmlCatalog_ProductController{
    ....
}
```

From that point, what else must be achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your controller

```
require_once 'Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php';   
class Company_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController {

}
```

In your config.xml

```
<config>
    ....
    <admin>
          <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Company_Adminhtml before="Mage_Adminhtml">Company_Adminhtml</Company_Adminhtml>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
          </routers>
      </admin>
</config>
```

See [Magento: Overriding Core Files (Blocks, Models, Resources, Controllers)](http://prattski.com/2010/06/24/magento-overriding-core-files-blocks-models-resources-controllers/)

Answer (score 1):

Magento won't find the controller as it would search for `Mage/Customer/AccountController.php`. I guess the only way is in fact `require_once` a controller php class file.

I think [**here you can find a complete solution for this**](http://inchoo.net/dev-talk/how-to-extend-magento-core-controller/).

The other, much less elegant way is to copy the whole controller you want to extend, and let it extend `Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action`.

Edit: Or `Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action` for admin area controller.